# How to access the original tarball when packaging for Debian?

Tags: python, debian, packaging, deb

I am packaging a piece of Python software that uses DistUtilsExtra. When running `python setup.py install` in my `debian/rules`, DistUtilsExtra automatically recompiles the translation template `.pot` file and updates it directly in the source repository. As a result of that, the second time I execute the packaging commands (be it with `debuild` or `pdebuild`) an automatic patch file gets created (since it thinks I have manually updated the .pot file). This patch is obviously unwanted in the Debian package and I am searching for a way to not generate it.

One solution would be for DistUtilsExtra to not change the .pot file in the source repository, but for now that's not possible. I am thus testing another solution: create an override for the `clean` instruction that extracts the original .pot file from the `.orig.tar.gz` tarball, done like this in `debian/rules`:

```
override_dh_clean:
    tar -zxvf ../<projname>_*.orig.tar.gz --wildcards --strip-components=1 <projname>-*/po/<projname>.pot
    dh_clean
```

However I've been told on the debian-mentors mailing list that the original tarball is not assured to be located in `../`. I am thus wondering if there is a way to reliably access the  `.orig.tar.gz` tarball from inside `debian/rules`, like a "variable" that would contain its location?

Answer (score 2):

This is not strictly speaking an answer to the question *How to access the original tarball when packaging for Debian?*, but that's how I solved the problem that provoqued my question, so here it is:

I found an interesting [blog post by Raphaël Hertzog](http://raphaelhertzog.com/2011/01/28/3-ways-to-not-clutter-your-debian-source-package-with-autogenerated-files/) that explains how to ignore autogenerated files when building a Debian package. This is done by passing the `--extend-diff-ignore` option to `dpkg-source` in the `debian/source/options` file. I have thus removed the proposed command from `override_dh_clean`, and the unwanted automatic patch is not created anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution for automatically generated files is to delete them during clean.

Comment: tumbleweed, the .pot file is already present in the source files, the packaging process updates it. So deleting them during clean would actually be another modification to the source file. What I was trying to do is revert that file to its original state by copying it. However using the `--extend-diff-ignore` option actually solves this problem by letting me specify which autogenerated file to ignore. See my proposed solution to this question (which I'm not marking as the accepted since it's not actually answering the question, just proposing a way around it)

Comment: No, deletions are ignored by `dpkg-source` for precisely this kind of reason.